# android setting.db bluetooth_name

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm noticing a discrepancy when modifying bluetooth_name in settings.db on android 4.2.1.

I've run the following commands:

```
sqlite> select * from secure where name is "bluetooth_name";
60|bluetooth_name|Samsung Galaxy S III

sqlite> update secure set value = "TESTY" where _id = 60;

sqlite> select * from secure where name is "bluetooth_name";
60|bluetooth_name|TESTY

adb reboot
```

After reboot:

```
sqlite> select * from secure where name is "bluetooth_name";
61|bluetooth_name|Samsung Galaxy S III
```

The previous row has been deleted and a new one "61" was created by the system.

I'm wondering why this happens, how I can change this behavior, or how I can change the value of bluetooth_name with sqlite3.

Thanks